# Killing a PetalsESB Server in a Java programm

Tags: java, ubuntu, groovy, kill, pid

My Problem: I run a program in Java / Groovy. In this program, I start a PETALS ESB Server, which also runs on Java. 
I want to kill only the server and then start him afterwards again in the same java program.
In windows I would run the server in a new window and kill the new window, but in ubuntu every terminal shares the same PID. pkill java kills the server + program. Is there a way to just kill a java program while running another java program?
I am new to groovy and ant, so maybe there is a way to simulate "ctrl+c" to kill the server?

Answer (score 1):

Why not calling the "petals-esb stop" command line?